# Only one D3 Visualization is showing up on my page?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to get a bar graph and a pie chart to show up on my page, but only the pie chart is showing up for me. I want both the pie chart and the bar chart to show up. Could it be I have multiple src that are overriding each other? How can I fix this code so that both of my charts will appear on my HTML file.
Any suggestions would very much help, as long as I can get both graphs to show up.

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Charts</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- JavaScript file for the Data -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.1.3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?2.1.3">
  </script><!--Fetching from CDN of D3.js -->
  <script src=  
      "https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js">  
  </script> 
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css"> 
    svg {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
    }
   
    path.domain {
      stroke: none;
    }
   
    .y .tick line {
      stroke: #ddd;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<svg width="300" height="300"> 
    </svg>

    <script>

        var data = [600,1800,300,500]; 
        
        // Selecting SVG using d3.select() 
        var svg = d3.select("svg"); 
            
        // Creating Pie generator 
        var pie = d3.pie(); 

        // Creating arc 
        var arc = d3.arc() 
                    .innerRadius(0) 
                    .outerRadius(100); 

        let g = svg.append("g") 
                    .attr("transform", "translate(150,120)"); 

        // Grouping different arcs 
        var arcs = g.selectAll("arc") 
                    .data(pie(data)) 
                    .enter() 
                    .append("g"); 

        // Appending path  
        arcs.append("path") 
            .attr("fill", (data, i)=>{ 
                let value=data.data; 
                return d3.schemeSet3[i+1]; 
            }) 
            .attr("d", arc); 
            
        // Adding data to each arc 
        arcs.append("text") 
            .attr("transform",(d)=>{  
                    return "translate("+  
                    arc.centroid(d) + ")";  
            }) 
            .text(function(d){ 
                return d.data;  
                }); 

                

    </script>
    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });
 
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});
 
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");
    
tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You appear to be loading 3 versions of d3, is there any reason why you are loading: v2, v3, and d3.geom, in addition to v6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to address the direct cause of your grief (mismatched versions of d3 all occupying the same object: `d3`). Instead, let's make the direct cause of your grief obsolete, like d3v3 and d3v2, by removing the outdated code so that our visualization uses a consistent version of d3.

As a result, I'm going to treat the question as asking "How do I update my v3 stacked bar chart to v6"

Here's your v3 stacked bar chart:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });
 
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});
 
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");
    
tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Looks nice.

Let's upgrade it to d3v6. First, the great namespace flattening of d3 in d3v4 broke a lot of code, and it'll break yours too. You'll need to update the following (my apologies if I miss something in this list):

- d3.scale.ordinal ⟶ d3.scaleOrdinal
- d3.scale.linear ⟶ d3.scaleLinear
- d3.layout.stack ⟶ d3.stack
- d3.svg.axis ⟶ d3.axisLeft, d3.axisRight, d3.axisBottom, d3.axisTop
- d3.time.format ⟶ d3.timeFormat
- d3.time.format().parse ⟶ d3.timeParse()

The axis generators also no longer have an orient method, cause you choose the orientation when you choose the generator. Where you'd use: `d3.time.format("...").parse` you'd now use `d3.timeParse("...")`

But most changes are reserved for d3.stack(). This makes a few things simpler when creating the stack dataset. The arrays representing each bar no longer have d.y and d.y0 properties, instead just containing two numbers. This cascades through your code.   The x value of a bar is now d.data.year (or whatever property). This description is very broad strokes, the documentation is much more thorough.

We'll also change the scale you're using, the ordinal is great for mapping a discrete domain to a discrete range, but you have a continuous range, so we can use
d3.scaleBand instead.

Lastly, d3.mouse is no longer, as of d3v6. Instead of d3.mouse(this) we use d3.pointer(this).

Here's a d3v6 stacked bar chart:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "9", pears: "6" },
  { year: "2007", redDelicious: "12", mcintosh: "18", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2008", redDelicious: "05", mcintosh: "20", oranges: "8", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2009", redDelicious: "01", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "5", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2010", redDelicious: "02", mcintosh: "10", oranges: "4", pears: "2" },
  { year: "2011", redDelicious: "03", mcintosh: "12", oranges: "6", pears: "3" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "04", mcintosh: "15", oranges: "8", pears: "1" },
  { year: "2013", redDelicious: "06", mcintosh: "11", oranges: "9", pears: "4" },
  { year: "2014", redDelicious: "10", mcintosh: "13", oranges: "9", pears: "5" },
  { year: "2015", redDelicious: "16", mcintosh: "19", oranges: "6", pears: "9" },
  { year: "2016", redDelicious: "19", mcintosh: "17", oranges: "5", pears: "7" },
];

var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y")


// Transpose the data into layers
var keys= ["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"];
var dataset = d3.stack().keys(keys)(data);

// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }))
  .range([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d[0] + d[1]; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; })


var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.year); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[0] + d[1]); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[0] + d[1]); })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.pointer(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.pointer(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });
 
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});
 
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");
    
tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now I can replace your original d3v3 stacked bar graph in your code, remove the unneeded dependencies, and get the desired outcome.

Comment: I was able to get both of the graphs on my page, thanks!

Comment: I do have one more issue though. Im trying to create blank space between the two and I want the bottom graph to have its own <h2> title directly above it and instead it shows up next to the <h2> title for the pie chart. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd probably use separate divs for both visualizations and append headers and svg elements to each. If you're having difficulty with it you could post a new question showing the minimal amount of code to replicate the issue you want resolved (ie; without code that puts anything in the svgs themselves as that doesn't affect your spacing).